# Use tf.keras.layers.concatenate() as custom layer in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I want to make U-net using custom layers in tensorflow. I need use tf.keras.layers.concatenate there and that is my problem. Input tensors for all other layers I can add to layer in method call. But syntax for concatenate layer is tf.keras.layers.concatenate(input, axis) and I need something like this tf.keras.layers.concatenate(axis)(input), but it does not work. Can anybody help me please?
Thank you.

My code is something like this:

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.block1 = Conv2D(.....)
    self.block2 = BatchNormalization()
    ....etc.....
    self.decoder_concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(axis=-1) #that i need but it does not work

  def call(self, inputs):
     x = self.block1(inputs)
     x = self.block2(x)
     ....etc......
     x = self.decoder_concat([x, concatLayer]) #that i need but it does not work
```

Comment: You just need to use `Concatenate` with a capital C.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem. Note for others: arguments of concatenation in method call (in [ ] brackets) must be outputs of layers in method call (in my case, these are x-es). It can not be block from constructor (in my case e.g. self.block1), because we want to concatenate tensors (x-es) not layers (block1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section, for the benefit of the community.

After changing `tf.keras.layers.concatenate` to `tf.keras.layers.Concatenate` has resolved the issue.

`tf.keras.layers.Concatenate` which is used as a layer that concatenates list of inputs in Tensorflow, where as `tf.keras.layers.concatenate` acts as functional interface to the Concatenate layer. Please refer more details [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Concatenate)

Please refer updated code in below

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.block1 = Conv2D(.....)
    self.block2 = BatchNormalization()
    ....etc.....
    self.decoder_concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1) #that i need but it does not work

  def call(self, inputs):
     x = self.block1(inputs)
     x = self.block2(x)
     ....etc......
     x = self.decoder_concat([x, concatLayer]) #that i need but it does not work
```